Explain answer to "Adventure beginning by way of hill. One in 10!"
The clue, from Which magazine, November 2023:

Adventure beginning by way of hill. One in 10!

The answer, I believe, is "aviator" from the first sentence but I don’t understand the definition of "One in 10!"

The attribution could also help with a possible context: "One in 10" might be a reference to another clue, for example if the answer to 10 were "plane".

Thank you. The puzzle was in Which magazine November 2023. The answer to clue 10 was hot air balloon so yes 10 was a reference to another clue which hadn’t occurred to me. Many thanks for your prompt response to something I spent ages puzzling over!

tor = hill ?  that's a bit of a stretch.

A web search confirms that it is. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tor

@Jasen On the contrary. Devon has many tors, which are hills. Many have Tor in their names. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(rock_formation)

The clue "Adventure beginning by way of hill" can be broken up into 3 parts:

 "Adventure beginning" means "the beginning of the word Adventure" which is "A"
 "by way of" can be represented by the word "via"
 "hill" can be represented by "tor"1
1: Merriam Webster online dictionary, courtesy of Ed in comments

Adding the 3 parts together, you get:

 A + via + tor = aviator

And according to the OP in comments:

 The answer to clue 10 was hot air balloon, which there very likely was an aviator in the hot air balloon!

